# How to let the IDE know that I use ancestor variable?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

For simplicity, I only have 2 classes `TParent` and `TChild`.

```
TParent = class
protected
  FValue : Integer;
end;
```

```
TChild = class(TParent)
public
  property Value : Integer read FValue;
end;
```

If the `TChild` property `Value` uses the `TParent` variable `FValue` which is in another unit, the IDE always creates new variable when using auto-complete, which is a problem when adding new properties or methods and may cause unwanted errors.

```
TChild = class(TParent)
private
  FValue: Integer;
public
  property Value : Integer read FValue;
end;
```

However, if `TParent` and `TChild` are in the same unit, everything works fine. Is there any way to prevent this if I don't have the ability to move both classes to the same unit? Also I don't have access to a unit containing `TParent`. In this case, `TChild` is a component derived from `TCustomGrid`.

Comment: Often the best solution to a problem is to remove the problem. Once you have removed the problem, you don't need to find a solution. Don't use clashing names.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure how this will help. I can use any names, but the result will be the same.

Comment: @DavidHefferman - from my reading he has not declared the variable, he is simply accessing it.  If it is defined as protected in the the TParent class then it is available to him and there is nothing wrong with what he's doing ...

Comment: Oh, I thought you were creating these duplicate names. I see. Yeah, the IDE would appear to be at fault here. You'll just have to live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the nature of inheritance, more specifically, field visibility. The simple solution would be to introduce a property getter function with a higher visibility. For example...

```
TParent = class
protected
  FValue : Integer;
public
  function GetValue: Integer;
end;

TChild = class(TParent)
public
  property Value : Integer read GetValue;
end;

...

function TParent.GetValue: Integer;
begin
  Result:= FValue;
end;
```

Code completion is just following these same rules - it doesn't have visibility of the parent's field, so it generates a new one.

Comment: As I learned in Delphi not to use getters when they are not needed, I never thought of this solution. Although I don't have access to `TParent`, I can do the same in `TChild`.

Comment: @Triber "Although I don't have access to `TParent`" You didn't state that in your question. If `TParent` is in another unit that you don't have access to, that's a whole different scope. I assumed you did have access since you were mentioning them working while in the same unit.

Comment: it is still correct answer, without acces to another unit I can just introduce getter function in `TChild`. if the variable is protected, it does not matter where I create the getter, the result will be the same.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge - the Getter function does not need to be public unless you want to be able to call it directly rather than use the property.  A protected getter will be adequate and avoids exposing too much of the class internals.  (Something I know some people get very excited about!)

Comment: Just don’t use the IDE’s auto complete, type everything in. Or remove the private field of the child afterwards, then autocomplete will not add it again!